# nodejs express doesn't work with string replace or string manipulation?

Tags: node.js, express

```
  console.log(`Tweet is ${post}`);
  let splitted = post.text.split("$");
  console.log(splitted);
  let res = splitted[1].substr(0, splitted[1].indexOf(" "));
  console.log(res);
  let final = res.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, " ");
  console.log(final);
```

I get a tweet and i can see what a tweet is, then terminal is not showing any manipulated text.

But i am getting

```
    Tweet is {
  _id: 5f07027a7ec93029ccaa7a8b,
  text: '$pkpkpk',
  created_at: 2020-07-09T11:41:46.312Z,
  __v: 0
}
[ '', 'pkpkpk' ]
//Nothing here // Empty
```

*It gives me output for Tweet but not for variable **res** and **final**.*
I am using Twitter Lite

```
Twitter.stream("statuses/filter", parameters)
.on("start", (response) => console.log("start"))
.on("data", (tweet) => {
  //passing Tweet to replace function's etc
})
.on("ping", () => console.log("ping"))
.on("error", (error) => console.log("error", error))
.on("end", (response) => console.log("end"));
};
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can debug by adding more `console.log` after each operations to see the previous results.

Comment: @ShahinGhasemi Thank you! i have added output for console.log's but still getting empty string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this:

```
let res = splitted[1].substr(0, splitted[1].indexOf(" "));
```

you have to determine the upper bound of `substr` correctly

I guess this is what you want to do:

```
console.log(`Tweet is ${post}`);
let splitted = post.text.split("$");
console.log(splitted);
let res = splitted[1].substr(0, splitted[1].length);
console.log(res);
let final = res.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, " ");
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have no space in your text attribute.

```
let res = splitted[1].substr(0, splitted[1].indexOf(" "));
```

will be translated to:

```
let res = splitted[1].substr(0, -1); // because indexOf returns -1.
```

Therefore, you juste get nothing.

you can

```
console.log(splitted[1].indexOf(" "));
```

if you want to be sure about your index